# Having one text file be split into multiple text files with specific names in c

Tags: c

I have a text file that has a bunch of flight information with departure dates. (Will be linked the text file) I need to have that text file be split into multiple text files where each text file created only has one specific airline. There should be 4 text files created because there is AA, DL, OO, and F airlines. This means that the four text files that need to be created are AA.txt, DL.txt, OO.txt, and F.txt, and in each text file should only have its specific airline. So there should only be American Airline Flights in AA.txt and no other flights, etc. What would the code be like in C?

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char* arr[4] = {"AA", "DL", "OO", "F"};
    char airLine[350];
    char line[120];
    int noLine = 0;
    char **str = NULL;

    printf("Enter input file name:");
    scanf("%s", airLine);

    fp1 = fopen(airLine,"r");
    if (!fp1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    while(fgets(airLine, sizeof(airLine), fp1) != NULL)
    {
        if(strchr(airLine, '\n'))
        airLine[strlen(airLine)-1] = '\0';
        str = (char**)realloc(str, sizeof(char**)*(noLine+1));
        str[noLine] = (char*)calloc(350, sizeof(char));
        strcpy(str[noLine], airLine);
        noLine++;
    }
    for()
    {

    }
}
```

This is what I think needs to happen in the code in c.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *fp1;
    char* str[6] = {"AA", "DL", "OO", "F"};
    // want to have the first 2 characters don't know how
    char airLine[350];
    char line[120];

    printf("Enter input file name:");
    scanf("%s", airLine);

    fp1 = fopen(airLine,"r");
    if (!fp1)
    {
       return 1;
    }

    while(fgets(airLine, sizeof(airLine), fp1) != NULL)
    {
        if(// if the first 2 characters of airline doesn't exist inarray)             
        // write unknown characters in the array that are in the text
        // file otherwise do nothing
    }
    for(// iterate through the list of the collected string)
    {
        sprintf(line, ".txt");
        fp2 = fopen(line, "w");
        while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp2) != NULL)
        {
            if(// If the airline matches the airline in the current txt     file)
            // Then write the airline and create the file otherwise do nothing
            // prob fprintf maybe
        }
        // maybe close fp2 in here
    }
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the text file:

```
AA43 DFW DTW 2016-01-06 11:00
AA43 DFW DTW 2016-01-17 11:00
AA44 SEA JFK 2015-02-05 7:45
AA197 ORD BOS 2012-03-12 11:50 
AA1 JFK LAX 2016-07-02 9:00
OO7435 DTW PLN 2016-11-22 21:55
F9612 DEN MIA 2014-12-19 22:15
DL801 GEG MSP 2016-08-31 9:00
DL1087 ATL DAB 2016-04-10 12:05
DL828 IAH SLC 2012-06-02 7:45
```

Comment: Create a structure like `struct AirlineFile { char code[4]; FILE *fp; };` and create an array of those.  As you read entries from the file, find the airline code in the array of `struct AirlineFile`; if the code is not present, add it (and open/create the relevant file, and store the file stream pointer in the structure too).  At this point, you know the file stream to write to, so write the information to that stream.

Comment: I will try struct to see how it works. Just that when you have char code[4] you don't have to define "AA, etc" next to it? Like char code[4] = {'A', etc}

Comment: I'm under the illusion there may be some airlines with a 3-character code instead of just 2 — the 4 allows for that.  You'd create a record of that type containing `"AA"` in the code, and a file pointer for the file `"AA.txt"`.  You might or might not store the file name in the structure too.  When you come across the first AA record, you open and create the file and store the file stream in the structure.  On subsequent records, you note that the AA record exists and simply write to the file stream.

Comment: Is there some sort of direct relationship between this question and the other that you asked, which is asking how to sort this data?  Both questions seem to be tied together.....

Comment: Yeah there is. I was trying to figure out the sorting algorithm and apply to the question I posted here.

Comment: Judging from Wikipedia, [IATA Airline Codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airline_codes) can, in principle, be 3 characters, but they've not yet used any 3-character codes because some airline central reservation systems (still) can't handle them 20 years after they were announced.  Not all software is easily adapted to new circumstances.

Comment: By creating the struct how would you define it below in the int main function?

Comment: For creating the array do you mean the array of the struct itself. Like AirlineFile[whatever number]

Comment: Would the FILE *fp in the struct be different from the FILE *fp1 I have above in terms of the array being looped through the file itself. So does that mean FILE *fp1 is going to be the file that will be created

Comment: Also the struct has been made. Would the struct array be this: struct AirlineFile Airplane[n]. What would you put in the n because if the struct has the file and the characters for the {AA} then does that mean it should be 3 or should it be the lines that are in the text file

Comment: once the information in the array has been hold how would you be able to go through the array. I know it has to be in a loop but I don't know how to do that loop